# Eclipse: show error message only with keyboard

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, syntax-error

I love my keyboard. When coding(c++) in eclipse some time I do some syntactic mistakes. For example

```
std::String
```

it should have been std::string. I have been coding some java programs :p. What I m looking for is a way to display the error info

```
Type 'std::String' could not be resolved
```

using some keyboard shortcut. Instead of clicking on the bug icon that appears on the left side of the page. I know about CNTRL + '+' and '.'  . So how do I do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

In the source code editor, pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> while the (keyboard's) cursor is at at underlined text opens an overly window that contains the warning/error description. Works for JDT/java, so I assume it's the same for CDT/c++.

In addtion, (in JDT/java) pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> on methods/classes without problem shows the javadoc in an overlay window.

Comment: Thanks! That's great but how do I close the popup again?! Was expecting esc to work but it doesn't seem to. Maybe something up with my keybindings...

Comment: @MartinMcNulty ESC works for me. If not you could also switch to a different application (alt + tab) and switch back to eclipse right away.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a keyboard shortcut for that, but here is another solution:

Open up the "Problems" view (Window -> Show View -> Problems) and position it wherever you like.
You can configure what problems are shown there by clicking on the small triangle in the upper right corner. There you have to select "Show -> Errors/Warnings on Selection". This way only errors in the currently edited file will be visible.

Now you have all your syntax errors in view without any keyboard interaction at all.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: By clicking the triangle and selecting "New Problems View", this can also be an additional view so one doesn't need to replace the existing view.